# Users table with different roles and details

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let`s say we have the table users. In this table users there are 2 types of users, admin and user. They are linked to an role table through a role_id column but this doesn't matters so much, we can ignore the role table.

An admin has like 5 additional columns for the details and the User has around 25 additional columns for the details.

**One option** will be to insert all the details columns in the users table, and make them NULL. When inserting a new admin, all the columns for user details will be NULL and when adding a new user all the columns for the admin details will be NULL.

**The second option** will be to create 2 more tables like users_details and admin_details there will be related to the user_id, and store all the details inside them. And in the users table i will keep only the login info.

Which one you think is the best and why ?

Comment: You should have at least three tables here: users, roles, and role memberships. Third normal form.

Comment: yes i know, but this is just a basic admin role example ... the question was about the details, not the role relation

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking if you should create 2 another tables for the admin and user details or you should put all the details inside the users table...

Comment: So roles have nothing to do with it? And shouldn't have been mentioned in your question? And what's this admin table?  What's different between an admin user and an ordinary user other than the roles?

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, i edited my question details. So the Users will have about 25 columns for details like phone, dob, married etc, and the Admin will only have just 5 columns for phone, email, etc.

Comment: Why? I repeat what I said before. You need users, roles, and role members. You don't need a separate table for admins. What happens when a user becomes an admin? When an admin becomes a normal user?

Comment: I thought the question was simple, but not, i have to give extra details :) The users will never change the role ... so a user with a role of a user will never become an admin.

Comment: I suggest you're building in an empirical guess that isn't even necessary. Forget the admin table, just have users.